# How could one monitor MySQL replication?

Tags: mysql, replication

I am not a DBA, but I am interested in knowing how replication monitoring is done on MySQL severs.

In order to know if a slave is in sync with its master, one would typically check `Seconds_Behind_Master`, `Slave_SQL_Running`, `Slave_IO_Running`.

There are tools available like `mk-table-checksum` to verify replication integrity.

My question is, how else would a DBA like to monitor replication?

Answer (score 3):

Once I have asked the similar question there was ultimate [Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8762/does-seconds-behind-master-show-exact-slave-lag-from-master). Please have a look at it.

Then you will be clear with the

```
Seconds_Behind_Master
```

The Seconds_Behind_Master is not a good Parameter for monitoring the replication.

Try to use `mk-heartbeat` monitoring script. I use that and it's really reliable.

For documentation of mk-heartbeat, click [here](http://www.maatkit.org/doc/mk-heartbeat.html).

**UPDATE**
[image: Shows <code>Replication topology</code> in MONyog]
Try [MONyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/index.php) Web based application which has separate Replication tab and pretty easy to use, with lots of features

This will let you know Status of all slaves and Master on Replication tab for example: Replication topology, Master detail, Slave detail in a tabular format. Also, using Monitors page, you can get alert if seconds_behind_master lags behind certain threshold value.

You can also use the [MySQL Community Replication Monitor](https://launchpad.net/mysql-replication-monitor)

The community driven MySQL replication monitoring tools is a collection of scripts in SQL and other languages, to achieve the same result that others can get with expensive applications.

Comment: Thanks! I agree with you! But other than mk-heartbeat, do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @omggs : Do you need tools for that..?

Comment: I dont need tools for that, I Just need to know if there is any other metric that I should check to monitor replication and its integrity.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend (as mentioned in first reply) to monitor data consistency across all servers binded to your master, becouse for variety of reasons *sometimes* replicas are not 100% copies.

Some nice PHP script, that checks data integrity can be found here:
https://github.com/KredytyChwilowki/MySQLReplicaIntegrityCheck

It is an open source tool, very similar to "mk-table-checksum" but with one huge difference: it can check consistency on all binary log configuration modes: “statement”, “row” and “mixed”.