# Circular Replication, prevent failure

Tags: mysql, replication

I recently needed to setup MySQL replication across 4 servers, so that each one is a slave of another.

After several hours of tweaking I finally got this working - it was actually quite simple.  I am using MySQL 5.5.

What happens if one of the machines fails and the replication stops happening?

For instance, if there was a change on server 1, and server 3 failed during the change, the 4th machine will not know about the change.

What are possible scenarios to think about?  How can I mitigate this issue?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18711/replication-broken-list-out-of-sync-tables

Comment: Basically, if one of the chain breaks, then you are mostly hosed and have to reconfigure the entire thing from scratch.  Friends don't let friends do circular replication.  Just because you can, doesn't mean that you should.

Comment: I give +1 for Aaron.